# How to Select Text input after add dynamic html row

Tags: javascript, jquery

iam working on codeiginter project , i have a purchase form that user can search the spare parts items in input text with autocomplete, and this is working but after i press add button to ann new row to search another item ... the new row i cant search inside like the first one.

i want user after search and select the item then add new row to search another item to add it

Code for search

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Initialize 

 $("#itemcode").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // Fetch data
      $.ajax({
        url: 'spareList',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          search: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
              response( data );


        //=========================
        }
      });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      // Set selection

      $('#itemcode').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
      $('#itemname').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input
      return false;


    }
  });

});
```

Code for add new row

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 var count = 1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
   
  count = count + 1;
  var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_code' ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='item code' id='itemcode' /></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_name'  ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='item name' id='itemname'/></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_quantity'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='quantity' /></td>";
   html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_price' ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='price' /></td>";
   html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";   
   html_code += "</tr>";  
   $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
   
 });
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
  $('#' + delete_row).remove();
 });
 </script>
```

the #itemcode input for search

```html
 <!-- Spare parts items -->
<div class="form-group">
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading"><b>Spare Parts</b></div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group row">

    <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
     <tr>
      <th class="col-xs-2" >Item Code</th>
      <th class="col-xs-6" >Item Name</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2" >Quantity</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2" >Price</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2" ></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td  class="item_code"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="item code " id="itemcode" /></td>
       
      <td  class="item_name"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="item name" id="itemname" /></td>
      <td  class="item_quantity"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="quantity" /></td>
      <td  class="item_price"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="price" /></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
 Add
</button>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="inserted_item_data"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: where is your HTML Code and Are you using jqueryUI?

Comment: html code updated

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make the function in one document ready and make sure you use `class` instead of `ID`. Here is the code below you can try and [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3nw5t9k/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialize 
    someParts();

    function someParts() {
        $(".form-control").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                // Fetch data
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'spareList',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                        //=========================
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                // Set selection

                $('#itemcode').val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                $('#itemname').val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to input
                return false;


            }
        });
    }
    var count = 1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
        count = count + 1;
        var html_code = "<tr id='row" + count + "'>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_code' ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='item code' id='itemcode' /></td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_name'  ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='item name' id='itemname'/></td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_quantity'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='quantity' /></td>";
        html_code += "<td contenteditable='false' class='item_price' ><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='price' /></td>";
        html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row" + count + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button></td>";
        html_code += "</tr>";
        $('#crud_table').append(html_code);
        someParts();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var delete_row = $(this).data("row");
    $('#' + delete_row).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without unique IDs and without screes of HTML.

Do as follows:

- wrap the initial table row in `<tbody></tbody>`.
- eliminate `id="itemcode"` and `id="itemname"` from the HTML.
- wrap the `$(...).autoComplete(...)` code in a function, say `setAutoComplete()`, so it can be reused.
- create a prototype row from the original table row.
- set `setAutoComplete()` on the original table row.
- to add new rows, append a clone the prototype row to tbody and call `setAutoComplete()` on it.
- within `setAutoComplete()`, traverse the DOM from row to the input element on which the `autocomplete` plugin is to be set.
- within setAutoComplete's , `select` handler, traverse the DOM to find the corresponding `itemname` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ******************
    // utility functions
    // ******************
    function setAutoComplete($row) {
        $row.find('.item_code').next('input') // traverse the DOM to find the row's itemcode field
        .autocomplete({
            'source': function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    'url': 'spareList',
                    'type': 'post',
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'data': { 'search': request.term },
                    'success': function(data) {
                        response(data);
                        /* ========================= */
                    }
                });
            },
            'select': function (event, ui) {
                var $target = $(event.target); // the .item_code field on which autocomplete was set (needs to be tested).
                $target.val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text.
                $target.closest('tr').find('.item_name').next('input').val(ui.item.value); // find corresponding itemname field by traversing DOM.
                return false;
            }
        });
        return $row; // useful for establishing $rowProto below
    }
    function appendNewRow() {
        setAutoComplete($rowProto.clone().appendTo('tbody', $table)); // clone $rowProto, append to table and initialize autocomplete.
                                                                      // return vaue is dicarded.
    }

    // **********************
    // static jQuery objects
    // **********************
    var $table = $('#crud_table');
    var $rowProto = setAutoComplete($('tbody tr', $table).eq(0)).clone(); // find the initial row, initialize autocomplete on it and create prototype.

    // **************************************
    // append remove button to row prototype
    // **************************************
    $rowProto.find('td:eq(4)').append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove'>-</button>");

    // **********************
    // attach event handlers
    // **********************
    $('#add').on('click', appendNewRow); // with utility functions and reused jQuery objects in place, the "#add" event handler is really simple.
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); // No need to select by ID. Instead, traverse the DOM from the clicked element to its table row.
    });
});
```

*partially untested*

Notes:

- everything is in one `$(document).ready()` structure.
- `$rowProto` is used as a prototype rather than the row itself, in order to avoid cloning `<input>` element contents.
- `event.target` *should* identify the element on which autocomplete was set but is not documented in the `autocomplete` API (debug?)

Comment: OK, a couple of minor amendments. Try it again.

Comment: If my code is working for you can you please mark it as complete